# Writing a function to take single line string

Tags: python

I'm trying to define my own function that will convert all the characters to lower case on a string only if it consists of a single word.

`def to_lower(s):`

`return s.lower()`

I've got this so far and of course it converts the whole string to lowercase. But I cannot figure out how to get it to fail if a string is given that consists of more than one word. I thought about doing it based on length, but that obviously wouldn't work.

Edit: I've now gotten to the point where I have:

```
  if len(s.split(" ")) == 1:
    return s.lower()
  else:
    return s
```

But in the next step there is an assertion to confirm that it has been done correctly:

```
assert to_lower("hElLO WORLD!") == "hello world!", 'Unexpected lower case of hello world'
assert to_lower("123 RDDs") == "123 rdds", "Unexpected lower case of 123 RDDs"
```

And I'm getting an assertion error on the first "hello world!" because it seems to still be converting the whole string to lower case. This is literally the first step so I haven't done anything else to mess with it beforehand.

Comment: Why would you write your own function? there is already `lower` function in spark. To determine if string has more than one word, you can split it by space and check the size of the resulting array.

Comment: @blackbishop it's just a first exercise in writing our own functions.

Comment: @blackbishop I've done this and I totally understand why and how this should work, but it fails in the next command where there's a check to see if it works. That command is: ```assert to_lower("hElLO WORLD!") == "hello world!", 'Unexpected lower case of hello world'```

Comment: @blackbishop it's an assertion error. All i've tried is what's posted here as it's the first part.

Comment: When you use  `assert condition, msg` the message is printed when the assertion fails. Your function is correct and returns the expected result. But your assertion test is not correct. You want to do `assert to_lower("hElLO WORLD!") != "hello world!", "Unexpected lower case of hello world"`

Comment: @blackbishop I've just figured that out as well while playing around with it. That command was provided by my instructor and we were told not to edit it which is why I assumed the problem was with me. Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in your udf splitting the text by whitespace and then get the length of the resulting array:

```
def to_lower(s):
    if len(s.split(" ")) == 1:
        return s.lower()
    else:
        return s
```